# How to Integrate these two Queries into one Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Can someone please tell me how can I merge these two queries into one Query?

I have already tried this code but the problem here that it does not update the Adserver table.

```
with first as (
    select *, c_date = Current_date() from FRIDAY.Adserver where C_date IS NULL
),

second as (
    select * from FRIDAY.Adserver JOIN FRIDAY.Matching_Table 
    ON Adserver.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table.string_field_0

  ),
Tird As(
Select *, CONCAT(Cast(Date as String),"-",Second.string_field_0) AS New_IDS from Second 
) Select * from Tird
```

---

First I need to update the Adserver Table with the current Date:

QUERY 1:
UPDATE FRIDAY.Adserver SET C_date() = CURRENT_Date() Where C_date IS NULL ;

And then I would only pick the data with the current date:

QUERY 2:

With First As(
select * from FRIDAY.Adserver where C_date = Current_date()
),
Second As(
select * from First JOIN FRIDAY.Matching_Table1 
    ON First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_1 OR First.Placement_ExtID = Matching_Table1.string_field_0
),
Tird As(
Select *, CONCAT(Cast(Date as String),"-",Second.string_field_0) AS New_IDS from Second ) Select * from Tird

---

Is there anyway to combine the above Query 1 and Query 2?

Comment: As the SQL tag is also here some RDMS like PostgreSQL support  `WITH  ...  AS (UPDATE ... )  SELECT ....`  not sure if Google BigQuery supports this.

Comment: @Fawad - are you sure you are using BigQuery? please confirm

Comment: @ Raymond and @ Mikhail ... those queries are running and I am using BigQuery

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

A query can either change data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) or return data (SELECT). To do both "at the same time" code is necessary. But this depends on the used DB server.

For example, you could create a function that first executes the UPDATE statement and then returns the data from the SELECT statement. But as I said, if and how this is possible depends on the DB system.

Comment: Hi Mika, that seems to be a nice idea. Can you share any function defined and that is called in the Query as well. Thanks

Comment: I don't know BigQuery in detail, but I'm not sure if you can create functions at all. You have to be able to create them on the server side.